# How do I find the next business day: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, date

Given that date = 20170203 (yyyymmdd), how can I find the next business day, i.e. 20170206 in this case?

Comment: Use a combination of `day`, `datenum` and `datestr`.

Comment: Refer :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you post a query

Answer (score 4):

```
date = datenum('20170203','yyyymmdd');
NBD = nextBusinessDay(date)

   NBD =

   06-Feb-2017
```

or

```
date = datenum('20170203','yyyymmdd');
NBD = nextBusinessDay(date,1:5) % Sunday to Thursday, as in e.g. Israel.

   NBD =

   05-Feb-2017
```

or even

```
date = datenum('20170203','yyyymmdd');
NBD = nextBusinessDay(date,[3 5 6]) % random business days

NBD =

07-Feb-2017
```

Where the function nextBusinessDay is:

```
function nbd = nextBusinessDay(serTime,workdays)
w = weekday(serTime);
if exist('workdays','var')
    nwds = workdays(workdays > w);
    if isempty(nwds)
        nbd = datestr(floor(serTime + mod(7,w) + workdays(1)));
    else
        nbd = datestr(floor(serTime) + nwds(1) - w);
    end
else
    if w < 6
        nbd = datestr(floor(serTime+1));
    else
        nbd = datestr(floor(serTime + 3 - mod(w,6)));
    end
end
```

Comment: @ Adriaan, thank you for inspiring a more generic solution! The solution now accepts an argument `workdays` where you can define which days are business days (see examples in the edit).